# Having a singleton pattern in Go Wire injection

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I have a piece of code which is used to load configuration from file and parse it into a struct, I use this configuration quite often and hence I pass it around in the method parameters. Now I as my method parameters are increasing, I am looking at dependency injection and have settle with wire.

Now I have created a provider to load the configuration and an injector to provide the config struct. However each time I call the injection my file is read again, I want that the file is read once and the injection provided as many times as required without any additional loading.

Here is my provider:

```
// ProvideConfig config provider ...
func ProvideConfig() *config.FileConfig {
        var cfp string

        flag.StringVar(&cfp, "config", "config.json", "absolute path")
        flag.Parse()

    return config.Loadconfig(cfp)
}
```

Injector:

```
// GetConfig injector ...
func GetConfig() ConfigResource {
    wire.Build(ProvideConfig, NewConfigResource)
    return ConfigResource{}
}
```

Now when I call:

```
injection.GetConfig()
```

I see that ProvideConfig is called always. I can have a check in the provide config method the determine if the config is already loaded, I am not sure if there is a better way, something like a single instance loader which is built into the wire. I tried looking into the docs but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: There is some discussion related to it here: https://github.com/google/wire/issues/225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no built in way in `wire` to specify that a provider is a singleton / should only be called once.

This is accomplished in the usual way in Go, by using `sync.Once`. Your provider function can be a closure that does the expensive operation only once using `sync.Once.Do`. This is idiomatic in Go, and doesn't require any special provision from every library that wants to provide "single" loading.

Here's an example without wire:

```
type Value struct {
    id  int
    msg string
}

type ValueProvider func() *Value

// consumer takes a function that provides a new *Value and consumes
// the *Value provided by it.
func consumer(vp ValueProvider) {
    v := vp()
    fmt.Printf("Consuming %+v\n", *v)
}

// MakeSingleLoader returns a ValueProvider that creates a value once using an
// expensive operation, and then keeps returning the same value.
func MakeSingleLoader() ValueProvider {
    var v *Value
    var once sync.Once

    return func() *Value {
        once.Do(func() {
            v = ExpensiveOperation()
        })
        return v
    }
}

// ExpensiveOperation emulates an expensive operation that can take a while
// to run.
func ExpensiveOperation() *Value {
    return &Value{id: 1, msg: "hello"}
}

func main() {
    sl := MakeSingleLoader()
    consumer(sl)
    consumer(sl)
    consumer(sl)
}
```

If you're OK with the "singleton" value being a global, this code can be simplified a bit. Otherwise, it only calls `ExpensiveOperation` once, and keeps the value cached in a local inaccessible outside `MakeSingleLoader`.

Comment: Yeah I suspected so! I will have to fallback to the manual singleton pattern. Thanks!